# Stuck on process of trying to loop through files, import 2 rows from each TXT, split based on tab, and transpose results

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dataframe, transpose

I'm trying to loop through text files in a folder, copy 2 rows, transpose the results, append...repeat.  When I've iterated through all files, I want to save the final results to a new CSV.  Here is the code that I'm testing.  All text files are tab-delimited and I'm trying to use regex to split-on-tab.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os
import re

# Use a list here rather than a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
filelist = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\*.txt")
number_of_lines = 2
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        head = [next(myfile) for x in range(2)]
        df_csv = pd.DataFrame(head)
        csv = re.split(r'\t+', df_csv)
        transposed_csv = csv.T
        #head = head.T
        df.append([filename, transposed_csv])

# You can build a dataframe from that list at the end if you desire
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df, columns=[filename, transposed_csv])

results_df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\out.csv')
```

When I run the code, I get this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-65-a5af32617ab7>", line 15, in <module>
    csv = re.split(r'\t+', df_csv)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 213, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

All files are pretty much similar, but some have more columns/fields than others.  All I want is the first two rows from each file, and the file name, so I can see which is which.

Here is a sample from one file.

```
IDRSSD    RCON9999              RSSD9017        RSSD9050                RSSD9130       RSSD9200                 RSSD9220        TEXT4087
          MICR9999REPORT DATE   LEGAL NAME      CERTIFICATE NUMBER      CITY NAME      STATE ABBREVIATION       ZIP CODE        PRIMARY INTERNET WEB ADDRESS
```

What I want to end up with, is this.

```
file                                                            code        line_item
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt   IDRSSD  
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt   RCON9999    MICR9999REPORT DATE
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt   RSSD9017    LEGAL NAME
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt   RSSD9050    CERTIFICATE NUMBER
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt   RSSD9130    CITY NAME
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt   RSSD9200    STATE ABBREVIATION
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt   RSSD9220    ZIP CODE
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt   TEXT4087    PRIMARY INTERNET WEB ADDRESS
```

Comment: Can you pass a dataframe to a regular expression?

Comment: Lol.  I didn't notice that.  I just fixed that issue, re-ran the code, and I'm getting that same thing as before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) using `tab` as delimiter and `nrows` to get only the first 2 rows. Use `header=None` to avoid the inference of the column names, this way the transpose will produce two columns as desired.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

df = pd.DataFrame()
filelist = glob.glob("**/*.txt")
number_of_lines = 2

allfiles = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None, nrows=number_of_lines)
    df = df.T
    # replace Nan for IDRSSD items
    df = df.fillna('')
    df['file'] = filename
    allfiles = pd.concat([allfiles, df])

allfiles.columns = ['code', 'line_item', 'file']
allfiles = allfiles[['file','code', 'line_item']]
print(allfiles)

allfiles.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Output from *allfiles*

```
                       file      code                     line_item
0  input_folder\sample0.txt    IDRSSD
1  input_folder\sample0.txt  RCON0000           MICR0000REPORT DATE
2  input_folder\sample0.txt  RSSD0017                    LEGAL NAME
3  input_folder\sample0.txt  RSSD0050            CERTIFICATE NUMBER
4  input_folder\sample0.txt  RSSD0130                     CITY NAME
5  input_folder\sample0.txt  RSSD0200            STATE ABBREVIATION
6  input_folder\sample0.txt  RSSD0220                      ZIP CODE
7  input_folder\sample0.txt  TEXT4087  PRIMARY INTERNET WEB ADDRESS
0  input_folder\sample1.txt    IDRSSD
1  input_folder\sample1.txt  RCON1111           MICR1111REPORT DATE
2  input_folder\sample1.txt  RSSD1017                    LEGAL NAME
3  input_folder\sample1.txt  RSSD1050            CERTIFICATE NUMBER
0  input_folder\sample2.txt    IDRSSD
1  input_folder\sample2.txt  RCON2222           MICR2222REPORT DATE
2  input_folder\sample2.txt  RSSD2050            CERTIFICATE NUMBER
3  input_folder\sample2.txt  RSSD2200            STATE ABBREVIATION
4  input_folder\sample2.txt  TEXT4087   PRIMARY INTERNET WEB ADDRES
```